# Kivy: how to access IDs created in python code

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have this code below. I've set id by python code, but I couldn't access.

```
def abrirReceita(self,instance):
        instance.text = str(instance.ids)
```

I'd like to change the text with the number of the ID when I press.

Exemple: if I input the first button, change the text for '1', which is the ID I've passed.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.lang import Builder
import os
from kivy.core.window import Window
import sqlite3

KV = '''
ScreenManager:  
    Screen:
        name: 'telaSelecionada'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDToolbar:
                id: tb
                title: 'Drinks'
                md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            TelaSelecionada:
                id: telaselecionada
    

<TelaSelecionada>:  
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: mostraReceita
            padding: '20dp'
'''

Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"

class TelaSelecionada(FloatLayout):
    pass

class Aplicativo(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
            
    def on_start(self):
        i = 1
        for x in range(5):
            self.textLine = TwoLineListItem(text = 'change text', secondary_text = 'change text')
            self.root.ids.telaselecionada.ids.mostraReceita.add_widget(self.textLine)
            self.root.ids.telaselecionada.ids.mostraReceita.ids[i] = self.textLine
            self.textLine.bind(on_release = self.abrirReceita)
            i += 1
            
            
    def abrirReceita(self,instance):
        instance.text = str(instance.ids)

Aplicativo().run()
```

How do I access the IDs from python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to change the text with the number of the ID when I press.

Just pass the required args through method `abrirReceita` using `functools.partial` as,

```py
    def on_start(self):
            ...
            self.textLine.bind(on_release = partial(self.abrirReceita, i))
            i += 1

# Then in `abrirReceita` :

    def abrirReceita(self, id_index, instance):
        instance.text = str(id_index)
```

### Note:

The `ids` are not used here at all (actually you don't need that here for this *purpose*) !

---

### Update:

As, the `Widget.id` has been [deprecated](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-1.11.1/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=id#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.id) since version 2.0.0 you should use it only in `kvlang` **not** in `python`.

But that doesn't keep you from creating it as a dynamically added attribute. Thus you can do something like this (I modified the `on_start` method a little):

```py
    def on_start(self):
        mostraReceita = self.root.ids.telaselecionada.ids.mostraReceita
        for i, _ in enumerate(range(5), start=1):
        # Or just,
        # for i in range(1, 5+1):
            self.textLine = TwoLineListItem(
                text = 'change text',
                secondary_text = 'change text',
            )
            self.textLine.index = i
            # Or even,
            # self.textLine.id = i
            self.textLine.bind(on_release = self.abrirReceita)
            mostraReceita.add_widget(self.textLine)


    def abrirReceita(self,instance):
        instance.text = str(instance.index) # or, str(instance.id)
```